# Please explain the meaning of the word "Be'emunah" in the last paragraph of "Yekum Purkan"

Tags: tefilla, words, faith-bitachon-emunah

The last paragraph of "Yekum Purkan" - the prayer recited on Shabbat before Musaf - has a paragraph that praises the people that supply the needs of the synagogue and community. There is a phrase that says (my translation):

> ...And all those that occcupy themselves with the needs of the congregation *Be'emunah*

My understanding of "Be'emunah" means "with faith" or "with belief". What faith or belief is there with the **physical** action of supporting the congregational needs? Wouldn't a more appropriate word be *Bitzadaka* - with "charity" or a some term meaning "with generosity"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be'emunah means faithfully, like ([Shabbos 31a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=31&format=pdf)) נשאת ונתת באמונה -  Did you do business faithfully? In other words honestly, without taking undue personal benefit from the work.

See also Melachim II 12:16:

> וְלֹא יְחַשְּׁבוּ אֶת הָאֲנָשִׁים אֲשֶׁר יִתְּנוּ אֶת הַכֶּסֶף עַל יָדָם לָתֵת לְעֹשֵֹי הַמְּלָאכָה כִּי בֶאֱמֻנָה הֵם עֹשִֹים
>
> Moreover they reckoned not with the men, into whose hand they delivered the money to give to them that did the work; for they dealt faithfully. ([Mechon Mamre](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09b12.htm))
>
> And they would not reckon with the men into whose hand they would give the money to give the foremen over the work, for they did [the work] honestly. ([Chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15918#showrashi=true&v=16))

Similarly, at the end of Modeh Ani in the morning: Rabbah Emunasecha - Your faithfulness, as in reliability, is great.

That is the plain meaning. In Tanya ([Chapter 42](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/tanya/1/42) near the end) there is an additional connotation of Emunah - training, as in a craftsman (אומן) who is well trained through repetition. That could be applied here as well - working for the needs of the congregation competently and repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks. The Tanya angle is a really nice explanation as well. A bit of stretching of Ivrit, perhaps, as the correct term would be "B'Umanut".

Comment: Or better yet -- "with integrity." It echoes [II Kings 12:16](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09b12.htm), "for the craftsmen worked with integrity."

Comment: "faithfulness, as in reliability"....+1